# Bisect tool will not let me select any vertices

Tags: modeling, mesh, tools

If I am understanding the Bisect tool I can take my mesh, say a basic sphere, in edit mode, nothing selected on my mesh.  Select Bisect, choose my fill and clear inner/clear outer options and draw a line through my mesh.  Correct?

What am I doing wrong?

Every single time as soon as I click in my viewport area to start drawing the line, the tool resets to the tweak (Select box) tool.

I'm noob-ish trying to learn better ways of doing things than inserting a plane and doing a boolean modifier every time I want to split a mesh in two.

This happens even in a new instance of Blender. deleted default cube, lamp and camera and inserted a UV Sphere.  No other changes made.  Blender 3.1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello, Bisect will cut the select vertices/edges/faces, have you selected something in Edit mode. It's not clear...